# Material Chip chipStrokeColor is not being applied to Chip Element

Tags: android, material-components-android, material-components, android-chips

I am using Material Chips from the Material Components Library: `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0` I have created styles for Chips with custom background and state lists. The attribute `chipStrokeColor` is not being applied to the chips element. Even the attribute `checkedIcon` doesn't display on chips being checked.

Here's the style for Material Choice Chips:

```
<style name="Spectre.Chips.Choice" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/catamaran_bold</item>
        <item name="chipCornerRadius">10dp</item>
        <item name="chipStrokeColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="chipSurfaceColor">@color/iris_purple</item>
        <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/outlined_btn_state_list</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/outlined_btn_txt_list</item>
        <item name="chipIconTint">@color/box_input_state_list</item>
        <item name="rippleColor">@color/iris_purple</item>
        <item name="checkedIcon">@drawable/ic_check_white_24dp</item>
        <item name="android:checkable">true</item>
        <item name="chipStartPadding">10dp</item>
        <item name="chipEndPadding">10dp</item>
    </style>
```

Here's the Chip element in Layout.xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            style="@style/Spectre.Chips.Choice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/_18_20" />
```

Here's a display for the chips on the device:

[image: Material Chips on Android Device]

Comment: Did you try this : <item name="chipStrokeWidth">1dp</item>

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir Yes, I did try now yet it's not working

Comment: check background color and stroke color. It can be black?

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir default strokeColor = Yellow and background has state-list with black background as default colour so I guess the strokeColor should be visible.

Comment: I tried this code. It is working. I just add chipStrokeWidth. I see the stroke. even I added parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter" for check icon

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2MFx.png

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir I should used chipStokeWidth instead of strokeWidth and Chip Filter instead of Choice! Thanks a lot though 

Comment: You're welcome. Happy coding.

Comment: The style `Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice` has as default [`chipStrokeWidth=0dp`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.1.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/chip/res/values/styles.xml#L51). You have to override it in your style or in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Change parent style from `Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action` to `Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter` which supports stroke color change.

Better yet - Migrate to `Widget.Material3.Chip.Filter` all together.

More info [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Chip.md#filter-chip).